# Loading webview (to display website) in iOS application

Tags: ios, iphone, webview, app-store

I'm new to iOS development.

Inside my app (iOS native app), on clicking one tab, I need to load a website using webview inside the application just like using browserField in Blackberry. The website will be used to make some transactions/payments.

If this is done, will there be any problem publishing the app in iStore as the website included will be used for secure transactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use In-App purchase for payments which intend to purchase content, functionality, or services in your app.

If your app implements any external payment system/services for purchasing any of above, your app will violate the app-store guidelines and hence will be rejected.

For more info please read through [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html) section 11 "Purchasing and currencies". You will need to login with your AppleId.

Hope that helps!